# android studio 4.0 cannot load jdk class

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

I updated Android Studio to  latest version (4.0) and i am getting the following error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puOoi.png)

I tried to to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62119421/android-studio-installation-errors-cannot-load-jdk-class-com-sun-jdi-field) but did not get any proper idea as to what to do.

I tried to set the `JAVA_PATH` to latest jdk 14 from oracle site but that results in android studio not starting at all, it doesn't even give any error message, but when i add the path as `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8-0_221` i get the error message as seen in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAVA_HOME variable value must be the JDK location.
Android supports only Java 7 or 8.
Kindly set the JAVA_HOME to Java 8 (Download if you don't have it)

Refer these posts for further info:
https://jakewharton.com/androids-java-9-10-11-and-12-support/
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: Thank you, this helped me ! I installed openJDK 8 from this link https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot and set it to JAVA_PATH and it works now